# Uploading files to s3 and then storing the URL in Firebase - Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, firebase, swift2

I want to upload a png file to s3 and then getting the s3 file url to be stored in Firebase json format. The s3 portion works fine, but the Firebase function somehow goes into assembly code and doesn't run.

The message that I get is:

> Firebase was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.

```
func uploadToS3(writePath: NSURL) {
    let ext = "png"
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest.body = writePath
    uploadRequest.key = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    self.s3URL = NSURL(string: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/\(S3BucketName)/\(uploadRequest.key!)")!
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/" + ext
    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed ❌ (\(error))")
        }
        if let exception = task.exception {
            print("Upload failed ❌ (\(exception))")
        }
        if task.result != nil {
            print("Uploaded to:\n\(self.s3URL)")
            updateFirebase(self.s3URL) **this doesn't run**
        }
        else {
            print("Unexpected empty result.")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
func updateFirebase(url: NSURL){
   let ref = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(self.uid).childByAppendingPath("photos")
   ref.updateChildValues([url.absoluteString: true])
    print("updated firebase")
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does anything in the transferManager block get called? i.e. add a print statement within that block and see if it ever gets there. Also, is there some kind of expected return value from the block (return nil?). Lastly, what does **this doesn't run** mean? It never gets to that line or it crashes *at* that line?

Comment: it gets called, "Uploaded to :\n\(self.s3URL)" gets printed out.

the method updateFirebase(url: NSURL) doesn't run, instead "Firebase was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available." gets printed out in the console

ie let ref = self.userRef..........
and ref.updateChildValues...........

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your build settings are set to release instead of debug. That setting is in Project settings then Combined and toward the bottom in the Swift Compiler - Code Generation. Debug should be None and Release should be Fast. I think those are the default settings but worth a check

A second would be the Build Configuration is wrong. Select your project name at the top of the window and pull down to Edit Schema and Build Configuration should be set to Debug.

I ran into this a year or so ago and it was faster just to create a new project and import the files - your milage may vary.